# Why are there different formulas for the Quadratic Cost Function

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions, backpropagation, mse

Some sources suggest the Quadratic Cost Function as the following formula.

[image]

But other sources suggest otherwise.
[image]

The difference is marginal but one is 1/n while the other is 1/2n

What is the difference that I am not catching here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is copied verbatim from an answer of mine on Data Science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/53189/73930. Perhaps we should address this topic on Cross Validated, too, and have an explicit answer.)

A major reason for using MSE is to optimize the parameters of a regression model. From calculus, you know how to find the minimum of a function by taking the derivative. That puts a "2" out in front, which is irritating to keep writing, so it is reasonable to put a "1/2" at the beginning so the derivative doesn't need a constant out front.

We get away with it because the minimum of $f(x)$ and $f(x)/2$ is achieved at the same value(s) of $x$.